# Unable to find template Symfony2

Tags: symfony, include, twig

I would like to include a template in my view but it doesn't work, I have this error :

> Unable to find template "::StyleBlock/light-pattern.html.twig" in ::base.html.twig at line 46.

My code :

```
{% for zone in content.blocks %}
    {% set path = '::StyleBlock/' ~ zone.styles %}
    {% include path %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the details i have this message :

InvalidArgumentException: The file "views/StyleBlock/light-pattern.html.twig" does not exist (in: /var/www/gathena/app/Resources).

But the path is correct, i don't understand.

I use Symfony 2.3 and I have the good permission on my directory

Comment: You are sure that the template exists in `/var/www/gathena/app/Resources/views/StyleBlock/light-pattern.html.twig` ?

Comment: Owh missing Cms/CmsBundle i have replace by : {% set path = 'CmsCmsBundle::StyleBlock/' ~ zone.styles %} and i have this error : @CmsCmsBundle/Resources/views/StyleBlock/light-pattern.html.twig missing the / between Cms and CmsBundle

Comment: If I add the / in Cms/Cmsbundle i have this error :  InvalidArgumentException: Bundle "Cms/CmsBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file

Comment: Have whitelisted the assets in your `app/config.yml`? ..or as the error says added the bundle to your `AppKernel.php` ?

Comment: is that template in your `app/Resources/view` dir, or in `src/Cms/CmsBundle/Resources/view` ?

Comment: I don't have touch the config.yml, what i must do ?

Comment: @Wilq the complete path is : gathena/src/Cms/CmsBundle/Resources/views/StyleBlock/light-pattern.html.twig

Comment: There's an entry called `assetic:` in it is one option which is called `bundles` followed by some square brackets. Comment out this line with a `#` hash and see if it works.

Comment: @SirDerpington I have this : assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar The bundles line is not a comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have given wrong path, it should be:

```
{% for zone in content.blocks %}
    {% set path = 'CmsCmsBundle:StyleBlock:' ~ zone.styles %}
    {% include path %}
{% endfor %}
```

as for path `src/Cms/CmsBundle/Resources/views/StyleBlock/`

The first parameter is your bundle, second is the controller in this case `StyleBlock`, so your views are in your bundle in `Resources/views/StyleBlock` directory, last parameter is the template name which is defined by your loop variable in this case. It should only be your template name, without any absolute paths. All parameters are seperated by `:`

Comment: I have this error with this path : Unable to find template "CmsCmsBundle:StyleBlocklight-pattern.html.twig" in ::base.html.twig at line 46.  [1/2] InvalidArgumentException: Template name "CmsCmsBundle:StyleBlocklight-pattern.html.twig" is not valid (format is "bundle:section:template.format.engine"). That's strange

Comment: You miss the ":" I think

Comment: @Kev you are sure you given `{% set path = 'CmsCmsBundle:StyleBlock:' ~ zone.styles %}` and not forgot about last `:` ??

Comment: Oh yes that' right sorry, now i have this error :  InvalidArgumentException: Unable to find file "@CmsCmsBundle/Resources/views/StyleBlock/light-pattern.html.twig" with : `{% set path = 'CmsCmsBundle:StyleBlock:' ~ zone.styles %}`

Comment: Oh... I'm stupid I have forgot a directory... i'm sorry. Thank for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
::StyleBlock:light-pattern.html.twig
```

Comment: Same error : InvalidArgumentException: The file "views/StyleBlock:light-pattern.html.twig" does not exist (in: /var/www/gathena/app/Resources)

Comment: can you give me the entire path of your template file

Comment: It's gathena/src/Cms/CmsBundle/Resources/views/StyleBlock/light-pattern.html.twig